# GreenDao primary key on multiple columns

Tags: android, greendao

I am using greendao to maintain SQL database on Android. Right now I am facing a problem of generating entity with two columns as primary key. To be clear I have column1 and column2 both of them are Long values and they together form a primary key.

I tried to model it as

```
@Index(unique = true)
private Long column1, column2
```

but it is not working. I am getting unique constrain failed when trying to insert and when trying to inserOrReplace it simply replaces based on column1 id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved it by defining entity like this:

```
@Id(autoincrement = true) //I totally don't care about value of this field
private Long idLocal;

@Index //this are 2 columns that I use as primary key
private Long column1id, column2id;
```

I know that this probably isn't best solution but it is working. However bounty is still open and I will give it to anyone who can give me better solution.

Answer (score 3):

GreenDao doesn't support composite primary keys as you might expect.

[Issue 26](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/26) was opened on the github project regarding this, and [Issue 476](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/476) references it too.

You can try and work around it by having an ID for the primary key which references additional properties, but this won't allow you to set a unique restriction on your fields so you will have to validate yourself.

See also http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/modelling-entities/#Primary_key_restrictions

Comment: I was able to add unique constraints to fields by doing the following. For an example where we want a `customer` table to have unique restriction on both first and last name fields (bad in practice but just an example) you put information in the `@Entity` annotation (GreenDao 3) like this:

`@Entity(nameInDb = "customer",indexes = { @Index(value = "firstname,lastname", unique = true)})`

Comment: This is the best solution so far and it works perfectly. Greendao Entity modelling says the same. http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/modelling-entities/#crayon-5949da361cc17011493334